# What technique is used to create this banner?

Tags: print-design

Below I've posted a video from Anar Foundation YT channel. Child portrait and text changes according to observer's viewing angle and height. Does anyone what technique this is called and how they're made?

[image]

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zoCDyQSH0o&t=69s

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the same as used in 3D postcards. It's called lenticular image. In your case the the image is divided to narrow horizontal slices. A half of them, say the even slices, are shown to taller people and the rest (=the odd slices) are shown to shorter people. The even slices have one image and the odd slices have another.

In front of the image there's an array of cylindrical lenses which directs the light reflected from the slices to the wanted directions.

See this article for illustrations and more detailed explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_printing

In theory it could be made also with no lenses, only by having the alternative slices on the different slopes of narrow parallel ridges. I have never seen such printings and cannot imagine how they could be made in practice. The history section in the linked Wikipedia article says that "no lenses" versions were well known more than 100 years ago.

In 3D looking postcards the alternating slices are vertical.

There are print houses which combine customer's images to a lenticular image. The linked article says that the printing and the insertion of the lens array happen today in the same machine.

The effect is also used in ads which seem to live when one passes them and the effect was popular in toys before the era of modern display technologies.